# Integrating QGIS with third party application

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I want to integrate the QGIS with the third party application.  Suppose we add some line then it should reflect the same in the third party application.

If we can integrate QGIS with a third party application, then how is it done?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you wanting to put a QGIS map on your form or write a plugin for QGIS? Or is it that you want to see your edits made with QGIS in some other program? If this is the case it depends on your feature type, PostGIS would work best but shapefiles not so well.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your integration strategy.
Most likely you just want your third party application to be able to read the same database as what QGIS is using. In which case

Integrating QGIS with third party application will depend on the data sources more than QGIS itself.

So using compatible databases is the first step. Commercial databases that can handle geometry (Oracle/MS SQL) are the obvious first point of call.
But under the assumption that you are using QGIS because its open source, then your database will be open source as well. postGIS will be good option, or something even lighter, Geopackages (as they are simply SQLite databases).

If your third party application can read postGRES or SQLITE, then you are all set. From there, its all about structuring your database in the most appropriate way. You could setup separate tables for geometry and attribute data, that way your third party app only needs to worry about the tables that have attributes (and not worry about geometry tables). Or you could setup view tables that just grab attribute data during database transactions, and have the third party app read the view tables (maybe expose only them via a different user/schema).

Maybe put a bit more detail into your question

- what is the current data storage mechanisms used by QGIS
- What is the third part application?
- is there any architecture standard you need to follow for integration? SOA? Point-point?